# Scope issues in Android using Retrofit

Tags: java, android, callback, retrofit

I have an issue with the scope of a variable in Android using Retrofit:

In the MainActivity I use Retrofit to get the JSON reply into a POJO (ApiResponse), create a extendedJourney Object and add it to the extendedJourneyArrayList:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {        
    private ArrayList<ExtendedJourney> extendedJourneyArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    ...

    getAPIReply(...){
        service.getInfo(..., new getCallback());
    ...}

    private class getCallback implements Callback<ApiResponse> {
        public void success(ApiResponse apiResponse, Response response) {
            try {                    
                consumeApiData(apiResponse);
                }
        ...
        }
    }
    private void consumeApiData(ApiResponse apiResponse){
        ExtendedJourney extendedJourney = new ExtendedJourney(apiResponse, params);
        extendedJourneyArrayList.add(extendedJourney);
    }
    public void getData(View view){
        getAPIReply(...);
        //Do stuff with the extendedJourneyArrayList  
    }
```

Inside consumeApiData() everything is OK, i.e. the extendedJourney Object is correctly created from the apiResponse and other params and the extendedJourneyArrayList is correctly updated with the new extendedJourney.

However, in getData(View view), extendedJourneyArrayList  is empty.

How can this be solved? Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making an asynchronous call.
That means, that after the call to **service.getInfo(..., new getCallback());** the flow continues normally, until it's intrrrupted by the callback. 
 So you code in **getData(View v)** is probably excecuting before the response is received.

So you should do what you want with the data on the *callback* ( for example in the end of the **consumeApiData(..)** after the data is added in the list ), or do a synchronous request ( which you must do in a separate thread ).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Kushtrim for your answer. To solve the problem I make of use an AsyncTask to perform synchronous requests, the code now looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {        
    private ArrayList<ExtendedJourney> extendedJourneyArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
...
    public void getData(View view){
        for(int i = 0; i < NUM_REQUESTS; i++){
            new getAPIReply().execute(params);
        }

    }

    private class getAPIReply extends AsyncTask<Params, Void, ApiResponse>{
        @Override
        protected ApiResponse doInBackground(Coords[] coords) {
            return service.getRouteInfo(params);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ApiResponse apiResponse){
            try {
                consumeApiData(apiResponse);
            } catch (JSONException e) {...}           
    } 

    private void consumeApiData(ApiResponse apiResponse) throws JSONException{
        ExtendedJourney extendedJourney = new ExtendedJourney(apiResponse, params);
        extendedJourneyArrayList.add(extendedJourney);
        if(extendedJourneyArrayList.size() == NUM_REQUESTS) {
              //Do stuff
        }
    }
```